# before must be in the pushed stack of the current context

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am creating an iOS app using Xamarin Form PCL.The flow of the Page as
`Login page` -> `Page Main` -> `Page OrderList` -> `Page OrderItem` ->`Page Signature` -> `Page Camera`.The Issue is  From Main Page to Camera Page I can come without any issue but when i try to return from Camera page to OrderList page i am getting an exception `before must be in the pushed stack of the current context`. I don't know is going wrong. Because the same code running perfectly in  Android but not running in iOS.

```
 Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new OrderList(),  this);
 await Navigation.PopAsync();
```

complete Exception

```
  Message: before must be in the pushed stack of the current context
InnerMessage: 
StackTrace:   at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.NavigationProxy.OnInsertPageBefore (Xamarin.Forms.Page page, Xamarin.Forms.Page before) [0x00020] in D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\NavigationProxy.cs:150 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.NavigationProxy.InsertPageBefore (Xamarin.Forms.Page page, Xamarin.Forms.Page before) [0x00000] in D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\NavigationProxy.cs:59 
  at AT.PictureAfterSignature+<Process>d__9.MoveNext () [0x000a2] in E:\Projects\xamrine\Source\ATiOS\AT\AT\PictureAfterSignature.xaml.cs:422 
Source: Xamarin.Forms.Core
```

Hope someone know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Let's see if I understand. You want to navigate from the `CameraPage` directly to the `OrderListPage` ? if so, since `OrderListPage` is already on the stack only that it's 3 "pops" away why don't you just remove the `SignaturePage` the `OrderItemPage` and then just do a single Pop.

Comment: @A.Goutam It seems your `Page Camera` is not in the stack, how do you present the `Camera`? using `PushModalAsync()`? Also if you want to return to the `Page OrderList`, you can try to remove the other pages instead of create a new one.

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT i am opening the camera page by  `Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new PictureAfterSignature(), this);
                        await Navigation.PopAsync(); ` PictureAfterSignature is my camera page

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT the Same Code running very well for Android

Comment: @A.Goutam There may be some differences between Android and iOS on Navigation. You mean every time you want to show a new page, you always insert and pop? It means `Page OrderItem`, `Page Signature` and `Page Camera` are in the same level?

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT Every time when user going on next page i am using Navigation.InsertPageBefore()

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT For check the Navigation  Stack i used if (Navigation.NavigationStack.Count == 0 )                    {       }  and this condition is true

Comment: @A.Goutam Can you post a small sample to specify this? Since this is complex to say between so many pages, but it only occurs on `Page Camera`.

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT how can i share my code at above with my question?

Comment: @A.Goutam Then this is weird, before you insert and pop, the Navigation must have at least one page(at least current page is in the Navigatiuon).

Comment: @A.Goutam Try to make a blank app, with only insert and pop pages functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you get this error it may be because a dead page is calling the function. For example if you handle page transitions using a Subscribe event in your main page via

`MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Application>();`

When you "leave" the main page (for example, to go to a login page, that once logged in will create a new main page) via PopAsync() you need to first unsubscribe any events, else next time you call a navigation event, the dead page is still listening and will try to remove itself again when it's already removed. I hope that makes sense.

You could also check if `Navigation.NavigationStack` is empty and just return if it is, but that won't fix the underlying problem.